# How can a local account access a database on another computer?

Tags: windows-7, sql-server-2008, user-accounts

I'm not even sure if this is possible, but I figured I'd ask.

I have two computers, these computers are not part of a domain, but they are on the same network. On each computer, the local administrator account is set up the exact same way (has the same username/password). The two computers can see each other on the network, and are each part of a workgroup with the same name.

PC1 has SQL Server installed and an application that uses Windows Authentication to connect to SQL. This works fine.

PC2 just has the application running. How can it authenticate against the SQL server on PC1? I keep getting access denied.

I can't change the application to use an SQL user login. It has to be Windows Authentication, and I can't change the application itself. Is there any way to do this or a step I've missed somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try adding the user as pc2\username, however I believe that without a domain it won't work.  This article ([Choosing an Authentication Mode](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144284.aspx)) seems to confirm that:

"Advantages of SQL Server Authentication

- Allows SQL Server to support older applications and applications
  provided by third parties that require SQL Server Authentication.

  **Allows SQL Server to support environments with mixed operating systems, where all users are not authenticated by a Windows
  domain**."

Comment: I tried PC2\Username, but it just says it can't find the account.